# SQL script for multiple related conditions

Tags: mysql

Im new to sql and reasonably comfortable writing simple conditional clauses. However, Im stuck on how to order a query where there are multiple independent conditions.

For example, if I want to select a year where both Customer A and a Customer B reached a target order, I ideally want a **both** command. In the hypothetical example below I want to check any years where both Tesco and Sainsburys placed orders above £10k. I would like the answers 2010 and 2015

```
      Orders Table                            Name Table    
Order_Year  Customer_ID   Value     Customer_ID     Customer_Name
2010            A        £18,759           A            Tesco
2011            A        £6,264            B         Sainbsburys
2012            A        £5,803            C          Morrisons
2013            A        £4,716         
2014            A        £5,606         
2015            A        £13,971            
2010            B        £12,077            
2011            B        £5,291         
2012            B        £5,444         
2013            B        £4,520         
2014            B        £5,007         
2015            B        £13,540            
2010            C        £4,605         
2011            C        £4,910         
2012            C        £4,081         
2013            C        £5,748         
2014            C        £16,126            
2015            C        £5,525
```

The closest I've got so far is:

```
select order_year from orders
inner join name
on orders.customer_id = name.customer_id
where 1 = case
when customer_name = tesco and order_value > 10000 then 1
when customer_name = sainsburys and order_value > 10000 then 1
else 0
end
```

However this gives me an either/or answer (either tesco ordered over 10k or Sainsburys did). I understand why it gives this answer but I would like understand how to structure the query to give the answer when both conditions are met.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Im using mysql workbench 8.0

Comment: Please post some sample data and expected output. It will help us to understand your problem better.

Comment: Could you give us the database structure ? And some data example ? It seems uncommon that a table `orders` contains a column `year`

Comment: For a start each row of the table is tested for the condition in the `WHERE` clause, but customer A and B are disjunctive, ie. row will contain either customer A or customer B, never both. Thus if you use `AND` the condition will never be satisfied. You need to use `OR` in your `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group by` to group the years and `having` to check your condition.

```
select order_year from Orders o
join Name n
on o.customer_id=n.Customer_ID
where o.value>10000
group by order_year
having sum(case when Customer_Name = 'Tesco' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 
       and
       sum(case when Customer_Name = 'Sainbsburys' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

[***Check Demo Here***](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=188d6746f2e3ac220f1f742da6c0d34e)

Comment: You can move `amount_spent > 10000` into the WHERE clause

Comment: Thank you for your response Arun. This works if I only use date from 1 table. When joining multiple tables I get many false positives. Is there any amendment I can make to make it compatible with more than 1 table?